# Java Scanner does not work without new line before it question

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.out

I am new in the vast world of Java. I am sorry if this question has already an answer, but I've searched a lot and no clue. So I am doing this simple exercise:

```
    package exercises;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FifthTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Base Number: ");
        int base = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Exponent Number: ");
        int exponent = scanner.nextInt();           
        int result = 1, i = 1;

        do {
            result = result * base;

            i++;
        } while(i <= exponent);
        System.out.println(result);
    }    
}
```

It is working fine. But when I remove these two lines:`System.out.println("Enter Base Number: ");` and `System.out.println("Enter Exponent Number: ");` my Eclipse IDE stops executing the program. Can someone explain why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see your problem. The program works fine in IntelliJ. It just doesn't prompt you for input. Does Eclipse give you an error?

Comment: I checked in Eclipse Photon and have find no problem with the code. Everything is Ok even without those two lines.

Comment: @SergeiVoychuk well I run it with Eclipse and without these two rows Sys.out.. it doesnt even open the console, so that I can type my inputs.

Comment: It's very strange I think that the problem is in Eclipse and not in the code. I've tried once more and everything is Ok. Try to create a new fresh class.

Comment: I suggest check the IDE settings and if the still problem exists, reinstall the IDE. It is not the problem with the code. It is problem with IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the system out functions the program does not stop running. Instead it is waiting for input from the user as your calling Scanner, which gives the illusion that the program has stopped running. Put in an input ( twice as you have two Scanner input requests) and hit enter and it will continue the execution.

Comment: @Jwitz as I have commented above, I run it with Eclipse and without these two rows Sys.out.. it doesnt even open the console, so that I can type my inputs.

Comment: Sounds like it's an IDE issue. It's definitely not to do with your code.

Comment: thanks a lot , reinstalled Eclipse now it's working fine!